Appositive -with closing statements
https://www.grammar.com/the_correct_way_to_use_commas_with_names_and_titles
If when writing an obituary and one wrote as a closing comment in a written obituary not in direct voice:

She will always be my friend Sarah.

What is the correct punctuation?

She will always be my friend - Sarah.  (dash?)

How does this differ from:

She was my friend from work, Sarah.

Where a comma is the correct punctuation as Sarah is the only friend from work therefore the traditional appositive structure set off with a comma is required?
Any accuracy in this New York Times article: seems too definitive. I think they are exceptions to the methods the writer applies.
https://archive.nytimes.com/opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/05/21/the-most-comma-mistakes/#:~:text=The%20basic%20idea%20is%20that,the%20end%20of%20the%20sentence).

If you must use punctuation mark: Sarah, my friend, will continue a friend.

"...my friend, Sarah."  Or  " .... 'my friend, Sarah' ."  since you're quorting a phrase.

As written, "She will always be my friend Sarah," would more likely be understood as direct address, i.e., you are speaking to Sarah about a third party. In that case, it needs a comma: "She will always be my friend, Sarah."
To employ an appositive, the following would be an (inelegant) example:
She will always be Sarah, my friend.

[Ooops... as @Lambie states, this is ambiguous, and can also be understood as direct address!
It appears, without context, appositive vs. direct address is often ambiguous. In the previous example, "She will always be my friend, Sarah," if one is talking to Sarah, it's direct address. If one is presenting a eulogy for Sarah, it's an appositive.
After this edit, I'll likely delete this most imperfect answer in a day or two.]

You reversed the idea. You need to change it: you are speaking to someone about Sarah.
